# get the Magento SOAP XML request parameters

Tags: soap, magento-1.9

I have crated a magento custom SOAP V2 Module,i have a xml request as follows.

```
from the firebug
----------------
    endpoint :http://202.129.197.46:4141/magento/vmagento9/inventory.php
    operationName :getFilterValues
    requestXml  :<GetFilterValuesRequest  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.promostandards
    .org/WSDL/InventoryService/1.0.0/">
      <wsVersion>Token1</wsVersion>
      <id>tvijay12312</id>
      <password>Token1</password>
      <productID>Token1</productID>
      <productIDtype>Token1</productIDtype>
    </GetFilterValuesRequest>
    version : 1.2.1
    webServiceName : Inventory
```

from this i want the id,password,productId and productIDtype. 
kindly share your idea to get this request data and pass to the login and mycustom api methods